# 2D Lighing in XNA

Tags: xna, 2d, lighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is 2D lighting implemented?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4177/how-is-2d-lighting-implemented)

I'm attempting to create a 2D game in 3/4th perspective (like Pokemon and the older Zelda games). The time has come for an attempt to create a lighting engine for it. Honestly, I've got no clue where to start. I've looked all over trying to find the math behind the subject or examples, and I've found nothing relevant. What's a good place to get started with 2D Lighing (shadows included) and how could it be adapted to 3/4th perspective?