# How can I simulate light using mask images on the iPad?

Tags: rendering, objective-c, lighting, image-effects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I achieve a torchlight effect (lighter area around a light source) in a 2D game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22159/can-i-achieve-a-torchlight-effect-lighter-area-around-a-light-source-in-a-2d-g)

I want to have a picture as a background, say this:

[image: background]

Then I would like to apply a mask, just a circle with blurred edges, so it looks like this:

[image: masked]

The idea is to simulate something emitting. Is this a good way of simulating light or should I use another method? And if so how? And I'm not really sure how to apply this method.

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate of the one I linked. For posterity, I have also edited your question to contain the same content as the SO question you linked to, since I have also flagged the SO question to be closed/deleted as a duplicate of this one (it is more appropriate here).

Comment: well you removed the iPad out of the title so no i got an answer for mac osx not for iOS so yeah thanks..

Comment: @user1586195 You can always edit your post and add "iPad" back in if that's so important to you. Also: The Core Image Framework is available on iOS, so the answer you got applies to iOS as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Core Image `CISpotLight` filter:

```
CIImage *inputImage = // your image here
CIFilter *spotlight = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISpotLight"];
[spotlight setDefaults];
[spotlight setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
CIImage *spotlightImage = [spotlight valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
```

See the [Core Image Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro) for more information.